# "realm migration needed", exception in android while retrieving values from realm db

Tags: android, realm

I am using Realm as a back end in my application. I have created one table named Setting. I added values in that table, by following the steps given on Realm's official site. 
But when I am going to retrieve values from that table in, I getting exception

> "io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: RealmMigration must be provided" on the line:" realm=Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());".

Actually, I am new to android and Realm, so finding trouble to understand what is problem.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

> EDIT: for new versions of Realm, Realm.init(Context context) is added

```
Realm.init(context);    
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration
                                     .Builder()
                                     .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                                     .build();
```

NOTE: With this config option, *any schema change will result in* **loss of data**, specifically:

- a field is added/removed
- a new RealmObject class is added
- an existing RealmObject is removed
- `@Required` is added/removed
- `@PrimaryKey` is added/removed
- `@Index` is added/removed

So it's primarily recommended while the app is in the development stage.

---

Or add a migration following the official docs:

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations

For example,

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(final DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

        if (oldVersion == 0) {
            RealmObjectSchema personSchema = schema.get("Person");
            personSchema
                .addField("fullName", String.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED);
            oldVersion++;
            ... 

  // hash code, equals
```

And

```
Realm.init(context);    
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder() 
                                 .migration(new Migration()) 
                           //      .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                                 .build();
```

Comment: `RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build()` on my realm version 2.0.0. `Builder(Context context)` is not public

Comment: If you are wondering how to use "config", try this: realm.getInstance(config);

Comment: or just `Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)` and so on.

Comment: If it still does not work, try reinstalling your app. Worked for me

Comment: @EpicPandaForce if we have two DBs to access in the same app, then how can one setDefaultConfig, wouldn't the realm always only use the defaultconfig file?. Please explain. I am having diffculty in understanding the concept, if I have more than one DBs to use.

Comment: @RishabhSahrawat if you have two configurations, then you should use the `name("otherRealm.realm")` argument of `RealmConfiguration.Builder`. You CAN have a `setDefaultConfig`, just be aware of what you are doing and when you are using the other configuration with `Realm.getInstance(otherRealmConfig)`.

Comment: I got it now. So, now I have two DBs in different schemas (files), when I wanna access them I am facing MIGRATION errors. After googling, I understood that I have to add one of the schemas (one file data) to other and then I can access the file having both DBs. But I am not sure exactly how to do that. Maybe you have any links etc.. I am following [this](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations) for now.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce , Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855380/how-can-i-replace-a-listobjects-with-object-field-in-realm about realm migration

Answer (score 20):

if you upload the app to store, the "delete and reinstall the app" will not working to other user, so you must working with "deleting" the realm and "reinstalling" the realm, not the app. here's the way to do it, hope it'll helps!!

```
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();

    try {
        return Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
    } catch (RealmMigrationNeededException e){
        try {
            Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration);
            //Realm file has been deleted.
            return Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            throw ex;
            //No Realm file to remove.
        }
    }
```

*EDIT*

For the newest Realm (3.0.0), Realm has changes the constructor structure, so you must do something like this :

```
Realm.init(context);    
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration
                                 .Builder()
                                 .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                                 .build();
```

Comment: Actually RealmMigration is the best answer for your problem, but somehow i can't implement RealmMigration to my apps :s

Comment: Thanks buddy this perfectly helps in solving issue

Answer (score 15):

You changed something to the realm structure.

In order to fix it you should include the [migration](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations) 
or simply remove the application and install it again.

Comment: Yupp, it worked, I re-installed app... Thanks a lot buddy

Comment: In case you're new, you can mark this answer as 'working' by 'accepting' it. (On the left a 'v' mark)

Comment: One more thing I want to ask is, as I have now retrieved  values in "RealmResults<List>". I have attributes in my table as "id,name, values". How can I get value of "values " column seperately.."???

Comment: you can only get the whole objects, so you can do a FindAll() and loop through the .getValues() part

Comment: Actually it is not showing option of getValues(), but I did get(i); but it is providing entire row and I want single value from that row. My code is "settingDataList.get(0);"

Comment: You could do it in a different way, Data data = realm.where(data.class).equalTo("values","my wanted value").findFirst()
which will return a single object of Data, and then you can do something with data.

Comment: Basically, the only way to get a single value is to get the whole row as object first, and then use the getter to retrieve the wanted value.

Comment: For example, I changed the version of Realm and got this error. Just reinstall it.

Answer (score 5):

That works for me

```
    Realm.init(context);
    Realm realm;
    try{
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    }catch (Exception e){

        // Get a Realm instance for this thread
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();
        realm = Realm.getInstance(config);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin version:

```
val realm = try {
            Realm.init(this)
            val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                    .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                    .build()
            Realm.getInstance(config)
        } catch (ex: RealmMigrationNeededException) {
            Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        }
```