# how can I save ArrayList <LatLng>savedPath in RealmObject

Tags: android, realm

I tried to save this object using Realm But I got this error

> Error:(24, 9) error: Type
>   java.util.ArrayList of field
>   savedPath is not supported

Here is my code :

```
public  class TrackingInfo extends RealmObject {
   private int order_id;
   private double savedDistance;
   private double savedDuration;
   private ArrayList <LatLng>savedPath;

public int getOrder_id() {
    return order_id;
}

public void setOrder_id(int order_id) {
    this.order_id = order_id;
}

public double getSavedDistance() {
    return savedDistance;
}

public void setSavedDistance(double savedDistance) {
    this.savedDistance = savedDistance;
}

public double getSavedDuration() {
    return savedDuration;
}

public void setSavedDuration(double savedDuration) {
    this.savedDuration = savedDuration;
}

public ArrayList<LatLng> getSavedPath() {
    return savedPath;
}

public void setSavedPath(ArrayList<LatLng> savedPath) {
    this.savedPath = savedPath;
}

 public TrackingInfo(){}}
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: i think you need to use List (the class in realm) and LatLng should be RealmObject or something like that

Comment: but i use android latlng so i can't make it extends realmObject , it is uneditable

Comment: there are some supported types that you can save other than that you need to create a RealmObject of it please check https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Object.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both List and LatLng cannot be stored in Realm directly. You will need to create a model object for LatLng and then use a RealmList object containing your model objects.

```
public class Location extends RealmObject {
    public Location() { }
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
}

RealmList<Location> savedPath = new RealmList<Location>();
//Add location objects to savedPath and store it in your TrackingInfo object
```

You will need to manually convert objects of the LatLng class to the Location class when you are inserting/retrieving from the database.

Comment: i saved my points latlng like this { pointsarr.add(new LatLng(latitudeloc, longitudeloc));} how can i save to my model object

Comment: For every LatLng object, create a new Location object (as above) and store the getLatitude() and getLongitude() values from the LatLng object in the Location object

Comment: i got this error
io.realm.exceptions.realmmigrationneeded exception realm migration must be provided

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940233/realm-migration-needed-exception-in-android-while-retriving-values-from-realm

Comment: completly true :)
thanx