# Can't avoid io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException

Tags: android, realm

I'm want to add new field in my model

```
public class NoteModel extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id; //new field
    private String note;
    private String header;
    private Date date;
    /*
     * few getters and setters
     */

}
```

And I don't want to make any migrations so

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);
        //if I'm right it's delete all data from db and change it's schema (that's OK for me)
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build()
    }
}
```

But I still got exception  io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Migration is required due to the following errors:
                  - Primary Key for class 'NoteModel' has been added.
                  - Property 'NoteModel.id' has been added.

It's happens in onCreate method (MainActivity.java).

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();      //error right here
```

What should I actually do? 
Get information from here: ["realm migration needed", exception in android while retrieving values from realm db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940233/realm-migration-needed-exception-in-android-while-retrieving-values-from-real)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)` after creating said config.

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build()
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config); // <---
    }
}
```